# phpmyadmin - PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PMA_Table in /**\n * @var string table name\n */ on line 18

Tags: phpmyadmin

> Error in Processing Request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal
>   Server Error
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class PMA_Table in /**\n
>   * @var string  table name\n     */ on line 18

Googling this error leads me to one chinese forums which doesn't help at all.

I tried reinstalling and it works for a while, but eventually stops working.

Comment: Can you post your SQL code or what you're trying to do that is leading to this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my company private server. The problem is more likely to be a server overload or physical memory deficit. Take a look at:

```
free -m
```

and

```
top
```

then check your

```
uptime
```

and consider rebooting the machine. This glitch in phpMyAdmin happens when MySQL/MariaDB refuses the incoming connection or timeouts, which is in most cases caused by high server load or not enough RAM... or actually both.